# TimescaleDB via helm, parameter changes won't work

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, bitnami, timescaledb

I've installed TimescaleDB via a helm chart on a Kubernetes cluster. And I want to adjust some settings in the `postgresql.conf` afterwards.

My `values.yml` is the following:

```
persistentVolumes:
  data:
    storageClass: nfs-client
    size: 1000Gi
  wal:
    size: 25Gi
    storageClass: nfs-client

secrets:
  certificateSecretName: timescaledb-2-certificate

networkPolicy:
  enabled: true

patroni:
  bootstrap:
    dcs:
      postgresql:
        parameters:
          max_worker_processes: 48
          max_parallel_workers: 16
          timescaledb.max_background_workers: 24
```

The settings from `patroni.bootstrap.dcs.postgresql.parameters` will be set during the initial installation.

But any later modification of these parameters followed by a helm upgrade cycle are ignored. Or, to be exact, they appear in the `/etc/timescaledb/patroni.yaml` but not in the `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` and those are not effective for the server (`show max_worker_processes;` in psql will show the old value).

Also restarting the pods won't help.

I've tried the chart timescaledb-single from https://charts.timescale.com and timescaledb-single from https://charts.fairwinds.com/incubator, both have the same behavior concerning these parameter changes.

Is this not suppose to work or am I doing it wrong or miss something?

(I've also tried the postgresql chart from bitnami. Here, the modification of settings after the initial installation works fine, but the mechanisms in the chart are completely different and unfortunately, the TimescaleDB extension is not available.)

Cheers, Wolfgang